# Android resource linking failed when trying to use custom font in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use custom fonts with new "android:fontFamily" attribute, added in Android O. While this works fin in xml:

```
android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_text_semibold"
```

using same construction in styles.xml like this:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sf_pro_text_semibold"</item>
```

leads to following build error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> Android resource linking failed
>     C:\Users\anro.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4125ed89f50d00591f7f19265a14b826\res\values\values.xml: AAPT: error: resource font/sf_pro_text_semibold" (aka com.example.fonttesting:font/sf_pro_text_semibold") not found.

Lots of tutorials say that it should work, but it doesn't. I suppose the problem is in build.gradle file, but I don't even know what to try to make it work (Downgrading to older support library version is not a good solution). Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fonttesting"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

So, does anybody know how to make custom fonts in styles.xml work with androidx?

Comment: could you add this line under CompileSdkVersion 
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

Comment: I've tried this, but same error again.

Comment: May be you are messing with `android.support` and `androidx` both. Sometimes AAPT error coming from that situation.

Comment: ++ does this item has fontFamily attribute ?

Comment: @Blasanka, I don't use android.support anywhere, so that's not the case.

Comment: @JamalAl-kelani, not sure what you mean. This android:fontFamily attribute is a part of style in styles.xml and this style is applied to TextView. But anyway, the app can't compile with this line in styles:
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sf_pro_text_semibold"</item>

Comment: Where have you stored the custom font file?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, it's in app\src\main\res\font folder

Comment: that seems weird  !  if you want build the app  clean and send it to me @ gamalalkelani@gmail.com, so I can configure what is the problem

Comment: Well, actually there is not much to see there. I just created new project with Empty Activity, Minimum API level 23, Language Kotlin, checked "Use androidx.* artifacts" and created "font" directory in resources with custom font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> AAPT: error: resource font/sf_pro_text_semibold" (aka com.example.fonttesting:font/sf_pro_text_semibold") not found.

There is a typo:

Remove the `"` char:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sf_pro_text_semibold</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sf_pro_text_semibold"</item>
```

Comment: I can't believe I've made such a stupid mistake and couldn't discover it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, my issue was given extension in style

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/muli.ttf</item>
<item name="fontFamily">@font/muli.ttf</item>
```

After removing the extension it worked for me.

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/muli</item>
<item name="fontFamily">@font/muli</item>
```